# progress on delayed data.submit() with blueimp file-upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I have a case where I have to save the form first - to get an id - which the uploaded files will be related to.

I works fine - but I have so far not been able to get any progress-data from the `data.submit();`.

Is it possible?

Here is my code: first collect the data-objects in a pending list:

```
var pendingList = [];
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dropZone: $('#drop-area'),
    uploadTemplateId: null,
    downloadTemplateId: null,
    url: multi_upload_action,
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data)
    {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file)
        {
            var row = $('<div class="template-upload">' +
                '<div class="table-cell">' +
                '<div class="name">' + file.name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="error"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="table-cell">' +
                '<div class="size">Processing...</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="table-cell">' +
                '<div class="progress" style="width: 100px;"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>');

            // fetching formatted size;
            var file_size = formatFileSize(file.size);

            row.find('.size').text(file_size);

            data.context = row.appendTo($(".content_upload_download"));
        });

        pendingList.push(data);
    },
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
    maxChunkSize: 8388000
});
```

Then - later on - send the files with extra info:

```
sendAllFiles = function (id, redirect_action)
{
    var total_files = pendingList.length;
    var n = 0;
    pendingList.forEach(function (data)
    {
        data.formData = {id: id};
        data.submit()
            .done(function (data, status)
            {
                n++;
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file)
                {
                    if (typeof file.error != 'undefined' && file.error)
                    {
                        alert(file.name + ': ' + file.error);
                    }
                });
                if (n == total_files)
                {
                    window.location.href = redirect_action;
                }
            });
    });
};
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me:

1. Create hidden start-buttons for each file on add
2. submit the master-form, and receive the extra information
3. Attach the new information to the url of the fileupload instance
4. loop over all start-buttons and initiate the click-event
5. Redirect the page after the last upload has finished

```
    sendAllFiles = function (id)
    {

        $('#fileupload').fileupload(
            'option',
            'url',
            phpGWLink('index.php', {menuaction: 'helpdesk.uitts.handle_multi_upload_file', id: id})
            );

        $.each($('.start_file_upload'), function (index, file_start)
        {
            file_start.click();
        });
    };

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dropZone: $('#drop-area'),
        uploadTemplateId: null,
        downloadTemplateId: null,
        autoUpload: false,
        add: function (e, data)
        {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file)
            {
                var file_size = formatFileSize(file.size);

                data.context = $('<p class="file">')
                    .append($('<span>').text(data.files[0].name + ' ' + file_size))
                    .appendTo($(".content_upload_download"))
                    .append($('<button type="button" class="start_file_upload" style="display:none">start</button>')
                        .click(function ()
                        {
                            data.submit();
                        }));

                pendingList++;

            });

        },
        progress: function (e, data)
        {
            var progress = parseInt((data.loaded / data.total) * 100, 10);
            data.context.css("background-position-x", 100 - progress + "%");
        },
        done: function (e, data)
        {
            file_count++;

            var result = JSON.parse(data.result);

            if (result.files[0].error)
            {
                data.context
                    .removeClass("file")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .append($('<span>').text(' Error: ' + result.files[0].error));
            }
            else
            {
                data.context
                    .addClass("done");
            }

            if (file_count === pendingList)
            {
                window.location.href = redirect_action;
            }

        },
        limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
        maxChunkSize: 8388000
    });
```